# Android Studio: how to save last activity in preferences in order to load upon restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

everyone.  I am a serious rookie here, so please forgive form / terminology issues to some extent.  I have researched this issue for literally hours already including all relevant strands here, I promise!  YES, I read the Android materials. I also have read the chapters of 3 books on this topic!

Everyone seems to use examples related to usernames or sound settings.  Am I using the wrong place to save this data type altogether?

As a first project as I try to learn Java and Android, I am writing an Interactive Fiction book - think about the Choose Your Own Adventure books from childhood.

I want the app to save the most recent activity name in the sharedPreferences so that the app (either automatically or via a "load game" button) goes back to the activity (page) the user was on last.

I plan to then edit the preference on each activity as the user goes through the book so that they can load anywhere.

Here's the code I *think* I am supposed to use to set up the preference:

```
SharedPreferences setpage = getSharedPreferences("page", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =setpage.edit();
editor.setpage ("page");
```

but I immediately get red letters on the "editor.setpage".  What am I doing wrong?

How would YOU go about saving the last activity in preferences?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No `setPage(..)` method of `SharedPreferences.Editor`

You can set values in this way :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("pageName","page");
editor.apply();
```

After when you want to retrieve data :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY PREF", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String pageName = prefs.getString("pageName", null);
if (pageName == null) {
    //"No name defined" is the default value.
}
```

You can check more about SharedPreferences from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Ok, this helped a lot, and I think I can store the activity name as a string now...  BUT how do I retrieve that string and make it a usable class name?     If I write code like this:  Intent gotopage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,// NEED STORED DATA HERE //);

                startActivity(gotopage);

Comment: yeh. you can save you data in preference and can retrieve whenever you want. what do you mean by `make it a usable class name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Save the activity name as a string

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPages", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("page", "PageX");
editor.apply();
```

Then get the activity from the SharedPreference and start it

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPages", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String page = sharedPref.getString("page", "PageX"); 
            Intent ActivityPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(page));
            startActivity(ActivityPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do cannot be achieved by SharedPreferences since it is quite basic. But i suggest you to learn about databases and their integration with Android. But sometime you may need SharedPreferences for example when you need to count how many times the user opens the app.

Let me tell the SharedPreferences using the code below.
First line creates new SharedPreference object and also second creates an editor In other words, you create a pencil to write something to SharedPreferences.
In fourth line, you get the previous amount of `count`. First arguement of `getInt()` method says that give me the `count`, if count does not exist return 0(it happens for the first time you open the app)
If you look `putInt()` method which arguements(things that are inbetween paranthesises) at the sixth line, first arguement which is `count` is a unique key in which you will store your data( data type depends on the method you call you may for example also use `putString()` for other cases). You will need this key when you want the get the value(as we did in fourth line), second arguement is the new value of `count`
Last line does this change.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

int previousCount = preferences.getInt("count", 0);

editor.putInt("count", previousCount + 1);
editor.commit();
```